# SQL longitude and latitude query wont show results

Tags: sql, google-maps

Hi I am trying to achieve an SQL query that shows results based on the distance between longitude and latitude. My problem is no results are showing with my current code.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
SQL;

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong.
My database was created using Googles developer code so it should work.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thankyou.

Comment: Your query would(when successfull) return 2 fields(id and distance), but you try to echo a field `name` which is not includet in the result-set

Comment: That's fixed it , silly mistake but its working finally - postcode pagination here we come! Thanks Molle!